# How to add usb 4G/LTE usb modem to STMP1 Android

Tags: android, android-source

So, I have downloaded the starter, developer and distribution packages from ST.  I can compile the
kernel and the android part.

I need to add a usb modem so that I can get an ip address in Android OS.

Is it as easy as plugging in the usb modem and it magically works?  Or will I need to modify the kernel and android to get my usb modem to be used for IP?

If the latter is true, what needs to be done to Android to get it to use the usb modem to force it to
get ip through the modem?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be enough to just connect the modem, if not you shouldn't need to do more than changing the internet input from the antenna to USB

Comment: Fascinating, I'll have to give it a try.  Thanks.  If I need to "change the internet input", how is that done?  In hardware or firmware?

Comment: I don't know how it's done but I found this
https://youtu.be/tQOA9o_X27A